# Different javascript in <head> on every post in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Is possible to make different javascript in head section on specify post?
For example:

Post number 1 contains in  section another javascript than Post number 2.
I'm talking about wordpress.

Thanks!

Comment: isn't it be possible to create multiple layout file and putting the head in that layout, then use different layout for each post?

Comment: yes it's possible to have per post javascript but it's not something you'd glue together that easily.

Comment: @samAlvin it is indeed possible.. But you need to put in a little bit of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**METHOD 1:** 
you can detect the post id and get the javascript according to that.

```
$currentPID = get_the_ID();
 <?php if ($currentPID != "false"): ?>
<!--home page custom JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/<?php echo $currentPId ?>.js"></script>
<!-- will get scripts/2.js if the post id is 2 and scripts/3.js if post id is 3 ......-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

get_the_ID returns post id as integer if it is present, else it returns false.

**Alternative methods:**

It's also possible to use predefined Wordpress function like is_page() and is_single() to detect posts and add javascript according to them.
for example-

```
<?php if (is_single( '2' )): ?>
<!--home page custom JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/post2.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or detect page

```
<?php if (is_page('home')): ?>
 <!--home page custom JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Scripts/homepage.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

remember all the code goes into header and webpage will always send extra HTTP request no matter if the custom javascript is present in folder

Comment: I will check and give a response! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use a **[Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)** so you can modify the `header.php` file.
Using the [**is_page()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function, you could assign different script blocks to different pages.

If you are looking for sinlge posts, you could use **[is_single()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/)**.

Answer (score 0):

yes and there are many ways to do it.

One of the simplest is by modifying the CSS and JS files that you will be loading in the functions.php by checking if the current page is X or Y template / page.

Example:

```
function load_scripts_and_styles() {
    // only load the CSS if the page is X or Y page
    if( is_singular() ) {
       wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libraries/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.7' );
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libraries/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.7', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts_and_styles' );
```